# Move SKSpriteNode by Y - Swift 2 + SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, skspritenode

I am working on a 2D game, and I'm using the Swift and SpriteKit. To begin, I started creating animated objects and moving to down. To create these "objects", I used the Spaceship (Asset image of Xcode).

See my code:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var spaceship = SKSpriteNode()

    var screenSize:CGSize!

    var gameStarted:Bool = false

    var moveAndRemove = SKAction()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        screenSize = self.frame.size

        self.createSpaceship()
    }


    func createSpaceship() -> Void {
        spaceship = SKSpriteNode()
        spaceship.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        spaceship.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 100)
        spaceship.setScale(1.0)

        spaceship.position = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width / 3, y: screenSize.height - 75)

        spaceship.zPosition = 1

        self.addChild(spaceship)
    }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if gameStarted == false {
            gameStarted = true

            let spawn = SKAction.runBlock { () in
                self.createSpaceship()
            }
            let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(1.5)
            let spawnDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn, delay])
            let spanDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnDelay)
            self.runAction(spanDelayForever)

            let distance = CGFloat(screenSize.height + spaceship.frame.height)
            let moveTargets = SKAction.moveToY(spaceship.frame.origin.y - distance, duration: 8.0)
            let removeTargets = SKAction.removeFromParent()

            moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveTargets,removeTargets])
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

But when I run the game, Spaceship stands still on display. I can not find it can solve.

Can someone help me?

**The Spaceship have to go down (Y), create copies, and move to down in Y.**

Comment: Try using moveBy instead of moveTo

Comment: It did not work, its still stopped.

Comment: You need to run the `moveAndRemove` action on each spaceship. I suggest you move the action definition to the `createSpaceship` method and run the `moveAndRemove` action on each spaceship that you create.

Comment: @0x141E It worked! Thank you so much! Post the answer for me mark as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the `moveAndRemove` action on each spaceship. I suggest you move the action definition to the `createSpaceship` method and run the `moveAndRemove` action on each spaceship that you create. For example,

```
func createSpaceship() {
    // This can be a local variable and combined into a single statement
    let spaceship = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
    spaceship.size = CGSize(width: 70, height: 100)
    spaceship.setScale(1.0)
    spaceship.position = CGPoint(x: screenSize.width / 3, y: screenSize.height - 75)
    spaceship.zPosition = 1

    let distance = CGFloat(screenSize.height + spaceship.frame.height)
    let moveTargets = SKAction.moveToY(spaceship.frame.origin.y - distance, duration: 8.0)
    let removeTargets = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveTargets,removeTargets])

    // Add the action to the list of actions executed by the spaceship
    spaceship.runAction(moveAndRemove)

    self.addChild(spaceship)
}
```

Comment: What does the moveAndRemove achieve? I understand moveToY but why is there a need to remove targets?

Comment: @Confused that's what the OP wants to happen after the target moves to the new location. See the question.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I'm asking the wrong person. I simply don't understand why there would be a need to remove "targets".