# How do I programmatically set the position of an SKNode within an ARSKView scene?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, arkit

I have an ARSKView scene containing some SKLabelNode items. The result can be seen here: https://sendvid.com/35ded50d

I want to write some code that loops over all of the nodes 60 times per second and updates their position. I don't want to use SKAction to move the nodes over time, I just want to set their 3D position to a specific value. How do I do this?

Some related questions:

[Move SKSpriteNode by Y - Swift 2 + SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459414/move-skspritenode-by-y-swift-2-spritekit)

[How do I programmatically move an ARAnchor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401173/how-do-i-programmatically-move-an-aranchor/44403042#44403042)

But these questions don't seem to give a clear, simple answer to "How do I update the 3D position of an SKNode programmatically 60 times per second?"

Note that setting the .position property doesn't seem to work. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destroy and re-create the `ARAnchor` associated with an `SKNode`. Set the new `ARAnchor` to the position you want to move the node to.

Note that you do not need to remove or recreate the `SKNode` itself. Just return the already-existing `SKNode` in the `ARSKViewDelegate`.